# How to add time to the current time in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

how to add 3 hours to the current time in php ?

```
$expired = time() + "3 hours";
$time = time();

if($time < $expired){
    condition....
}
```

Comment: $time = time() + 10800;

Answer (score 1):

The [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function will work.

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Comment: OP want to add 3 hour not 2 hour!!!!

Comment: Then add 3 instead of 2 in query. Above DATE_ADD is mysql function you can use it in query directly

Comment: Thanks sir. But i need to add the time in the code, not on the query